# How do I connect to teradata server from Debian 11 using teradatasql

Tags: python, teradata, teradatasql

When I try and connect to teradata, I get this error:

`OSError: /home/***/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/teradatasql/teradatasql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I installed teradatasql using `pip install teradatasql`.
I also installed `teradatasqlalchemy`

I cannot find much help online so any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The teradatasql driver only supports Linux x86-64 architecture right now. If you are installing on Linux ARM, then it will not work. Linux ARM support is planned for the future.

Comment: Will it work on a mac m1?

Comment: I got it working in docker by specifying the platform as `linux/amd64`

Comment: @AnuragSaxena Yes, the teradatasql driver supports Mac ARM.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can check out:

1. Check if you have the dependencies needed: `sudo apt-get install libodbc1`.
2. Check that its installed correctly `pip show teradatasql`. It should return the path.
3. See if the path is in your .bashrc/.zshrc file `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/teradata/cliv2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
4. Check if this file actually exists in that location `/home/***/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/teradatasql/teradatasql.so` If not, there might have been an issue during the installation.

Comment: libodbc1 and cliv2 are not used by the teradatasql driver But yes, `pip show` (and verify the Location) seems like a good start.

Comment: The `teradatasql.so` exists but somehow the library is not picking it up. I also installed `libodbc1` but same issue.